# Certificates for clusters

Tags: load-balancing, certificate, cluster

I have read the various threads regarding clusters (behind the load balancer) and certificates.

I am trying to implement this in our company.

Firstly Our compnay policy is not to allow exporting of certificates, so this is out of the question. I have been told that you cannot apply for a certificate with identical CN, i.e. www.example.com for server 1 and www.example.com for server 2. But logically this is the same as exporting except you generate new keys? Do the certificate authorities say "We will not accept same domain names but if you want to make them exportable the risk is with you?".

Secondly I was told that the follwoing would work:

```
CN= Server 1 
Subject Alternate Name (SAN)=www.example.com

CN= Server 2 
SAN=www.example.com
```

I see not difference between that and just putting it as a CN.

Thirdly I know that if the load balancer goes to the application level then the certificate can be installed there, but I just wanted answer to the above two without this being considered.

Could someone clear this cloud over my head?

Thanks in advance, help will be greatly appreciated

Christopher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with what Greg said, I don't think he actually answered your question about how to implement SSL certificates on servers behind a load balancer.

There is more than one way to do this.  One way is to install the same certificate on every web server.  It's a perfectly valid practice.  I'm sorry if your company policy prohibits you from correctly implementing SSL in a load-balanced farm.

Another way is by putting the certificate on the load balancer only.  This typically implies application-layer load-balancing, where the traffic from web server to load balancer on the LAN is unencrypted, and SSL is only used from the load balancer out.

Secondly, yes, you can use a SAN certificate. However, be advised that SAN certs are a little newer, and some older clients don't understand them. And in some cases they are looked down upon because putting several names on one cert mitigates its trustworthiness in a theoretical way... but that's a very minute point.

This article makes for very good reading about the various methods of load balancing:

http://1wt.eu/articles/2006_lb/

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly Our compnay policy is not to allow exporting of certificates.

This is a naive and stupid policy.  Disallowing export of the cert is a gui function only.  The full cert is still exportable, just not by the people that need to do their job.

https://www.isecpartners.com/tools/application-security/jailbreak.aspx

Comment: I have seen that it is possible to export an "unexportable" cert, but isn't it a risk? What if it was exported to a rogue server or someone took my personal Certificate to act like it was me? Not arguing but discussing. I do understand your point though: If you cant control it why put the law in.

Comment: If someone has access to the existing server/files where the cert with private key is located, you don't control where it can be transferred.  This is why you should always use strong private key protection for certificate private keys.